# Django Static Video Wont Play On Chrome or Edge

Tags: python, html, css, django, heroku

I have a landing page that is a Django project and hosted on Heroku. For some reason I cant get the landing page video to play on Chrome or Edge. Firefox it works fine, here is my html code. The video that is in question is surrounded by the video tag.I should also add it works fine on my dev server on any browser. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
{% block content %}
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
 <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <!--Font Awesome-->
 <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9571fdc7fc.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
 <!--JS-->
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src= "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Custom CSS -->
<link rel ="stylesheet" href={%static "forms/css/home-styles.css" %}>
<title>Missing Link</title>
</head>

<body>
 <secion class ="showcase">
 <header>
 <h2 class ="logo"> <img src="{% static "forms/chain.png" %}" alt="logo" class ="logo"  height="42" width= "42"> Missing Link</h2>
 </header>
 <video autoplay loop muted>
  <source src="{% static "forms/landing_video.mp4" %}" type="video/mp4"> </source>
 </video>
 <div class ="overlay"></div>
 <div class ="text">
 <h2> IT Data Systems</h2>
 <h3> Believing In Something Better ! </h3>
 <p> </p>
     {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                  <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="/dashboard" role="button">My Dashboard</a>
                  {% else %}
                  <p>If you arent a current user, please contact your local administrator. </p>
                  <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="/account/login" role="button">Login</a>
                  {% endif %}
 </div>
</section>

<section class = "footer">
<!-- Footer -->
<footer class="page-footer font-small blue pt-4">
 <!-- Copyright -->
<div class="footer-copyright text-center py-3">Newmark Education IT Data Systems © ML V 1.04  Alpha 2019-2021 Copyright
</div>
</footer>
</section>
</body>
</html>
  
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What does the browser console say?

Comment: Compatibility
'-ms-filter' is not supported by Chrome, Chrome Android, Samsung Internet. Add 'filter' to support Chrome 53+, Chrome Android 53+, Samsung Internet 6.0+.
Other
Audit usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform
Page layout may be unexpected due to Quirks Mode

Comment: Can we look at this live somewhere? I don't think the code alone provides enough information here, this might also have to do with how the server returns the video (response headers), or something else in that direction.

Comment: Is just the autoplay not working, or can't the video be started using the native browser controls either?

Comment: I updated the code , sorry didn't see my errors there with the br and footer. However its the same outcome. So the autoplay doesnt work , but I have no way of testing it manually since I don't have any controls to try and play the video.

Comment: Then _set_ the `controls` attribute ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-controls

Comment: So if I set the control attribute I get the controls at the bottom of the video, however they are not useable. I can click on play and nothing happens.

Comment: Have you tried a different video file then? If possible, one from a different source (in case the encoding settings used to create this one, have anything to do with it.)

Comment: Sounds like the video is probably using a codec that Chrome doesn't support. (Remember, mp4 is only a container format, but the actual video codec used can be one of several.)

Comment: Yeah you are probably correct, I have not tried a different video . I will deft give that a try. If it is a codec issue, would it be better to make this video an AVI ? Its short with no audio.

Comment: I'd probably rather go with H.264 or WebM - that should cover all relevant browsers, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Browser_support

Comment: Im going to try H264

Comment: It worked with webm, thanks for helping me Cbroe. I appreciate it.